# Is there a way to do cross beta matrix with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The pandas corr function is really fast. Even for a table with a 1000 columns x 200 rows it doesn't take more than a minute to calculate a cross correlation matrix.

I was trying to use a for loop to compute the slope between each pair of columns and it was taking much longer. I went back and tried to just use correlation in a loop and that was also taking a long time.

So I guess I have two part question. How is the pandas corr function working so fast. Is there a similar method to to compute the pairwise slope between each column?

Here is an example:

here is table

a b
0 0

1 1

In that case slope(a,b)=1

a b
0 0
1 2

In that case slope(a,b)=2

Comment: Any time you a for loop in conjunction with pandas, it's very likely it will degrade the performance because it will not be vectorised properly. It's one of the reason why Pandas is fast in some aspect. As for the other question, could you elaborate what exactly is a pairwise slope?

Comment: if you have column A: 0,1 and Column B: 0,1 then then slope of those two columns is 1. Its y=Mx+b.

Comment: Could you update your question with your attempt with the for loop please? I would have thought (0,1) and (0,1) together has undefined slope but guess I am thinking about something else.